# Laravel weird behavior orderByRaw(field())

Tags: php, laravel, behavior

I'm creating a multi roll registration system. And I'm trying to list all existing rolls. These have to be sorted ascendingly on the amount of permissions they have assigned to them. (in this example: User first, Moderator second and Admin third)
I cannot define the rolls in the code because new rolls can be created and existing rolls can be deleted. (exept for the user and admin roll)

I retrieve the permission count of all the available rolls and place them in a array with the id of the roll.

the array per_count returns the following ids:

```
2, 4, 3
```

Id's:

- 2 = User
- 3 = Admin
- 4 = Moderator

However, When I execute the following query:

```
Roll::orderByRaw("FIELD(id, ?)", array($per_count))->get()
```

It reverses the order and I get

- 3 Admin
- 4 Moderator
- 2 User

Controller:

```
 public function index()
{
    // Check if user is authorized to use this action, else redirect to login page
    $this->authorize_action(__FUNCTION__, $this->classname);

    foreach (Roll::all() as $roll) {
        $rollpermission['id']    = $roll->id;
        $rollpermission['count'] = $roll->permissions->count();
        $permission[]            = $rollpermission;
    }

    $this->array_sort_by_column($permission, 'count');

    $per_count = array();
    foreach ($permission as $per) {
        $per_count[] = $per['id'];
    }

    $foo = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($per_count), '?'));
    return view('roll')
        ->with('roll', Roll::orderByRaw("FIELD(id, " . $foo . ") desc", array_reverse($per_count))->get());
}
```

I managed to get it working correctly with the array_reverse function. 
However it is sloppy and should not be necessary. And I cant find the reason why the query reverses the results.
Can somebody explain to me why the results are reversed? Thanks

Comment: Try using `DB::enableSqlLog()`, then do your Roll query, then `dd( DB::getQueryLog() )` to output the actual sql going on.

Comment: Result is "select * from `roll` order by FIELD(id, ?)"

Comment: Is there any parameters?  They'd be in another index from the query.

Comment: +bindings: array:6 [▼
      "select" => []
      "join" => []
      "where" => []
      "having" => []
      "order" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:3 [▼
          0 => 2
          1 => 4
          2 => 3
        ]
      ]
      "union" => []
    ]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this role query?  Also, it looks like you're wrapping your array in another array `array(array_reverse($per_count))` maybe should be `array_reverse($per_count)`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the second array was an accident (i will edit that out). i'm just using array_reverse($per_count). The result should be ascending according to the $per_count array, but when I run the query it returns descending. It's weird and uncorrect behavior. And I was wondering if it is my bad or this is indeed incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderByRaw()` expects the second parameter to be an array of bindings, not an array to implode for one binding.  But on the other hand, if you implode it, it will be passed in as one string `'2, 3, 4'`, when you need a comma delimited list of numbers. Do this instead:

```
Roll::orderByRaw("FIELD(id, " . implode(", ", $per_count) . ")")->get();
```

Which will yield:

```
select * from `[table_name]` order by FIELD(id, 2, 3, 4)
```

Also, you may want to check the difference between [roll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll) and [role](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/role) before you code too much ;)